# Add a new value "on the fly" if it doesn't exist in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select field on a page and users should be able to add a new value which doesn't present in the select. The select uses select2 plugin with the default searchbox functionality.

I think it should be like this:

1. a user starts to type a value they needs
2. if they find what they want - they select it
3. if doesn't - they just keep typing the value to the end
4. then submit the form with the new value.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For version 4:**

Check out [the documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html).  You want the `tags: true` option.  If you need a custom function to assign the new `id` and `text`, it's called `createTags` and is passed in as an option, for example:

```
$('#el').select2({
  tags: true,

  createTag: function(term) {
    return { id: ..., text: ... };
  }
});
```

The [release announcement](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) also describes how to do this using data-attributes (under the section "Declaring options using data-* attributes")

```
<select data-data="[{id: '1', text: 'One', id: '2', text: 'Two'}]" data-tags="true"></select>
```

**For version 3:**

Almost the same as version 4 (above) but `createTags` used to be called `createSearchChoice`.  The [version 3.x docs](http://select2.github.io/select2/) are excellent -- I highly recommend looking them over.  See the example under the "Events" section, and how to use `createSearchChoice` under the "Documentation" section.

Comment: Thanks @Travis, I have tried tags option, but it allows multiple selection. Is there any options for single selection?

Comment: That's unrelated to creating new items.  If you don't want multiple selection, don't use `multiple: true` in the JS option object (you can also explicitly set it to `multiple: false`).  Also, make sure you don't have `multiple="multiple"` as an attribute on your select element.

Comment: OMG, you are absolutely right, tags didn't work for me because a select is in modal dialog, and the dialog had a "tabindex=-1" property which makes searchbox unreachable for some reason.